# What is the multiline_join function from the utitilies module?

Tags: python, spss

I have to read a program someone else wrote without comments and understand how it works. It uses a function called multi_line join and I don't know what it is or where to find it. The program combines python and SPSS to produce an excel workbook.

Comment: Check its import statements to see from where `multi_line` is getting imported.

Comment: It says it is from utilities